# I'm trying to use grep command

Tags: linux, command, arp

I'm new to Linux so it may sound silly.

I'm trying to execute a command

```
sudo arp-scan -l | grep DEVICEMACADDRESS
```

1. where does the output of this command gets saved.  ? ?
2. How I can append time once the given mac address is found. ? ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking here. The output doesn't get saved (except as stdout). You can however save it as variable or write/append it to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1:
Grep by default prints output to STDOUT (standart output), which is, in your case, terminal.

If you want to save the output to the file, use output redirection:

```
some command > file #this will write file anew (any file will be overwritten)
another command >> file #this will append to file, (file will be created, if doesn't exist)
```

If you want to save the output to variable, use following syntax:

```
NAMEOFVARINUPPERCASE=$(whole command)
```

Please note there are NO spaces around =. Also note, that this variable is available only to current terminal session. However, you can always `export` it, or save it to file.

Ad 2:

Use following syntax:

```
(command_to_find_mac && echo $(date)) >> file
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer, mark it as Accepted with the gray tick under voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

> where does the output of this command gets saved. ? ?

Ans: Your just piping here this will direct to STD_OUT that is your terminal in this case.

If you want to save redirect this to file.

> How I can append time once the given mac address is found. ? ?

Ans: just use this while redirecting to file, `echo $(date)`.

**for example :**

```
ls  | echo $(date)
tor 13 apr 2017 10:30:02 CEST
```